# How do I set limit for an image moving?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a Maps website like Google Map. I found a way to drag an image(div) to move. But I don't want it to go beyond the screen. Once it goes beyond, the white background shows up. I want to set limit for the image so when the edge of the image hits the edge of the window, it can not move. What I want is not something to keep the image inside of a container, because the image is bigger than the window and how it works is moving the image around.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  const ele = document.getElementById('dragMe');

  const mouseDownHandler = function(e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
  };

  const mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
    const dx = e.clientX - x;
    const dy = e.clientY - y;

    ele.style.top = `${ele.offsetTop + dy}px`;
    ele.style.left = `${ele.offsetLeft + dx}px`;

    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
  };

  const mouseUpHandler = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
  };

  ele.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #cbd5e0;
}

.draggable {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #cbd5e0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="draggable" id="dragMe">
      <img src="Texture/test map.png">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'll compute the new top and left values based on the mouse movement, but you’ll slap on some constraints. The `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` give you the screen’s dimensions, while `ele.offsetWidth` and `ele.offsetHeight` tell you how big your image is. Use these to set up boundaries where the image should stop being all draggy.

```
const mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
  const dx = e.clientX - x;
  const dy = e.clientY - y;

  // Calculate the new position
  let newLeft = ele.offsetLeft + dx;
  let newTop = ele.offsetTop + dy;

  // Get the dimensions of the window and the image
  const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const imageWidth = ele.offsetWidth;
  const imageHeight = ele.offsetHeight;

  // Define the boundaries
  const leftBoundary = screenWidth - imageWidth;
  const topBoundary = screenHeight - imageHeight;

  // Constrain the new position
  newLeft = Math.min(Math.max(newLeft, leftBoundary), 0);
  newTop = Math.min(Math.max(newTop, topBoundary), 0);

  // Update the position of the element
  ele.style.left = `${newLeft}px`;
  ele.style.top = `${newTop}px`;

  // Update the starting point for the next movement
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;

};
```

Comment: You could use the "Copy snippet to answer" button to integrate your function with the OP's code, if you were feeling charitable.

Comment: What if the size of the image is smaller than the window? Because game world mpas are not always bigger than the window. In that case, the image just don't move with your code.